# Pitas are paper thin on one side

Tags: bread, pita

My problem is when the pittas do puff up, one side is paper thin, and tears easily when you try to put anything on it.  Any tips?

Comment: Your recipe and method would be helpful in determining any problem. One side of a pitta is usually very thin, but perhaps not paper thin.

Comment: Are you using a preheated baking sheet (or stone) in very hot oven? (245C/475F)

Comment: i.e. uneven heat while cooking

Comment: Again, without details on at least the 'method' you are using, it is possible to be of assistance only in an entirely hit-or-miss fashion. Please think to provide some details. Are you using a cookie sheet? Is it dark in color, or shiny? Are you baking at 450°F? You're not oiling the cookie sheet, right? Et cetera.

Comment: I wonder if this is actually a case of https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/93005/bread-crust-separated-from-interior, masked by the pita geometry.

Answer (score 1):

Uneven rolling of pitas can usually cause this problem. Make sure you shape even with roll pin & keep it half centimetre thick!

Answer (score -1):

I find, whenever baking very well proofed flat breads such as pizza, that the top tends to turn into one big bubble if you don't take the time to pop them when they start. Proof that this is a common problem is the fact that they sell purpose made "pizza bubble poppers" at my local restaurant supply. I admit this is mostly speculative not knowing the recipe or details. Is it yeast leavened or chemically leavened, etc..

Comment: In pita the bubble is desirable and important; one big bubble should form to get the expected "pocket" structure.